# \pgfmathifthenelse not working correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf

Would anyone help me understand why this code compiles to a blue square grid, instead of a blank document?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0, 1, 2, 3}
    \foreach \j in {0, 1, 2, 3} {
        \pgfmathparse{0 ? 0 : 0}

        \draw[white, fill=blue, opacity=\pgfmathresult] (\j, \i) rectangle ++(1, 1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Grid]

The result I get, on both my machine and Overleaf is a grid, when it should be empty. I was able to use a similar pattern (i.e. using ifthenelse then using the result as opacity) to make a much more 'complex' diagram , but for some reason applying it to this simpler case fails, and I don't understand why.

[image: Cube]

Comment: You wrote `fill=blue`. Why is it strange that you get blue things?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The opacity should be set to 0 if the expression is evaluated correctly, so the blue squares should not appear.

Comment: The parameter to `opacity` doesn't get accessed until the `;`. You will need to use `opacity/.expanded=\pgfmathresult` or just directly `opacity=0?0:0`. If you need the value more than once on different paths, the macro `\pgfmathresult` isn't safe to hold it. Use `\pgfmathsetmacro` or the [`evaluate` key of PGFFor](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf/foreach/evaluate) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a specific macro for this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0, 1, 2, 3}
    \foreach \j in {0, 1, 2, 3} {
        %\pgfmathsetmacro{\myopacity}{0 ? 0 : 0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myopacity}{(\i+\j)/10}
        \draw[white, fill=blue, opacity=\myopacity] (\j, \i) rectangle ++(1, 1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I used variable opacity just for testing.

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I'm curious though, what's the reason \pgfmathresult is not enough?

Comment: Probably because the `\draw` is using some pgfmath operation internally...

Comment: @Rmano Quite likely. But it shouldn't…